# Sorting and pagination for data in table

Tags: angularjs, pagination

JS:

```
  $scope.viewAccount = function(){
                debugger;
              $scope.displayAccount=true;
                $scope.showviewAccount = true;
                       $scope.showListAccount = true;
                $scope.showAddAccount = false;

  var json = {

  "json": {
    "request": {
      "servicetype": "6",
      "functiontype": "6014",

           "data": {
        "shortname": $scope.model.selectShortName,
        "groupzname": $scope.model.selectGname,
        "city": $scope.model.selectCity,
        "activationstatus": true,
        "details": false,
        "sortbasedon": $scope.groupzname,
        "orderby": "desc",
        "limit":10,
        "offset":$scope.pagination
           }

    }
  }
};
  UserService.viewListAccount(json).then(function(response) {

      if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage == 'Success')
                        {
                   $scope.tableData = response.json.response.data;
                        }
              }); 
        };
```

HTML :

```
  <tr data-ng-repeat="data in tableData" dir-paginate="data in tableData |orderBy:sortkey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10" pagination-id="pagination1">
        <td  class ="stylethecontent" >{{ data.groupzcode}}</td>
        <td  class ="stylethecontent" >{{data.groupzname}}</td>
        <td  class ="stylethecontent" >{{data.shortname}}</td>
        <td  class ="stylethecontent" >{{data.city}}</td>
        <td  class ="stylethecontent" >{{data.state}}</td>
            </tr>
```

I need to do sorting as well as pagination for the table data given above. I have nearly 150 records. offset in json request is for pagination from which record need to show the datas and limit is for number of records need to show in table which I hardcoded as 10. sortby is for sorting. I doesn't know to handle them in html page , since I am new to angularjs as well as in Var JSON in my JS you can find offset and limit.

Comment: Where is your try at a sorting algorithm? Do you send up all 150 records at the same time? If not, where is the backend code that limits the rows?

Comment: I doesnt know to handle them in html page , since I am new to angularjs as well as in Var JSON in my JS you can find offset and limit.

Comment: If you have a control over your back-end, I recommend (as the rows are only 150, which is not much) to handle the pagination from the front-end completely (using a third-party derictive, and there is many on github)

Comment: If you select the 10 elements to be displayed in your backend, what do you expect your sorting to sort on? Your 150 rows, or the 10 rows that you sent up to front end? If Backend does everything, all your frontend have to know is how many pages there are left, which backend should tell you.

Comment: I think I can use ng-change in case of sorting. But what about fixing pagination. for now I have 150 records but later it will be more than 10000 records that why we going for pagination in backend.

Comment: Once I already wrote a similar answer here. About a table with sorting. I still have this plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/gRcuB4ciB3zJ0kqtPxYp?p=preview
It's not just your solution, but it's pretty generic. You can change it for your needs.

Comment: Its really helpful , thank you .